# How to install clang (11) without xcode?

Tags: development

My brother gave me ssh access to his macbook (`uname -a` says 19.6.0). I'd like to compile a few simple c files with clang (specifically clang and not gcc). I grabbed the clang 11 mac binary from the official site and move all the folders into `/usr/local/`. `which clang` gives me `/usr/local/bin/clang`. If I do `clang main.c` it just hangs. Even `clang --version` hangs

How do I properly install this? There's no xcode or developers tools on it

Comment: Please add (at least) the version of macOS to your original question

Comment: @SteveChambers ??? It's there. (Darwin) 19.6. Maybe it's 10.15.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew walks you through this command line install.

- https://brew.sh/

Basically, call `xcode-select --install` and have your brother click OK one time to approve the installation.

Comment: I tried that and got some error about it not being on the update server. I found out the reason why it hangs. The OS prompts the user about the app not being signed. Except I can't see it on the terminal. Is there a way to turn it off so all apps can run? Even if it's temporarily (I'll only need to build/test code once a week)

Comment: I don’t know a way to subvert this security step with the easy install. This step seems  intentional by Apple to prevent someone that runs malware from getting the tool chain installed surreptitiously without positive confirmation from the owner. Why not have your brother click OK or establish remote log in via screen sharing?

Comment: I think I misspoke. When I use clang++ 11 AFTER doing that, the OS complains about the app. However there was only 2 things it complained about I think the second was the linker. I'm able to compile code fine now thanks